# How to change value of form from drag/drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop feature in my web app, which is shown below.  I am trying to get the items that are dragged into the the #contributors div to be placed into a textbox named personalassessment_set3 but I'm not able to do so.  Any advice?

form

```
<p>
    <label for="personalassessment_set3">Set3</label><br />
    <input id="personalassessment_set3" name="personalassessment[set3]" type="text" />
</p>

<input type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="$('#personalassessment_set3').val( $('#contributors').val() )" />
```

Drag/drop

```
<script>
function dragUser(user, event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('User', user.id);
}
function dropUser(target, event) {
    var user = event.dataTransfer.getData('User');
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById(user));
}
</script>

<section id="user-levels">
    <div id="unassigned" ondrop="dropUser(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">

        <a draggable="true" class="user" id="leonardo" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">Compensation</a>
        <a draggable="true" class="user" id="raphael" ondragstart="dragUser(this, event)">Benefits</a>


    </div>

    <div id="contributors" ondrop="dropUser(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
        Ranking
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing onclick which don't accept any jquery based method or wrapped object.
You should try this instead:

```
<input id="test" type="button" value="Set Value" />
<script>
   $(function(){
       $('#test').on('click',function(){
          $('#personalassessment_set3').val( $('#contributors').val() )
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: When I add this code, the value in the textbox doesn't change after I move elements from #unassigned into #contributors.